# sending email to gmail account using phpmailer

Tags: php

```
<?php
    require_once 'PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';
    require_once 'PHPMailer-master/class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php';
    require_once 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    require_once 'PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;

    //$mail->SMTPDebug =2;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Username = 'zhaider113@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $from = 'shahghafoor439@gmail.com';
    $mail->setFrom($from, 'Ghafoor Shah');
    $mail->addReplyTo($from, 'Ghafoor Shah');
    $mail->addAddress('zhaider113@gmail.com', 'zeeshan');

    $mail->Subject = 'This is subject';
    $mail->Body = 'This is the body of email';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body of email';
    $mail->send();

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Messag could not send';
        echo 'Mailer error:' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'mail hasbeen send';
    }
    ?>
```

> I try to send email but it not send and give error message  which is:SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting */

Answer (score 0):

try with `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`

See full example at PHPMailer's gmail example below: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

Comment: i try this also but can't work, can i change any thing in xampp file

Comment: I's been some time since I last used XAMPP, but I remember there being an option to disable sending emails... also check `php.ini`

Comment: i change php.ini and sendmail.ini fles but they can not work and in XAMPP SMTP is enable which is before this change is disable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include correct [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) Library.

And make this changes

> Some Servers not response for SSL(Secure). So that change this `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`
>
> And In your code you **have two Mail sending option** `$mail->send();`

```
//$mail->send();//Comment this
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Messag could not send';
    echo 'Mailer error:' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'mail hasbeen send';
}
```

Now **either mail sent** Or **either** It will **print Error log**